Pgfplots fill between gives missing number error
I am trying to fill the area between two curves with fill between, but I get the "Missing number, treated as zero" error. Without that line, it compiles fine. It should not come from my installation, as I get the same issue on Overleaf. Here is an MRE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,ymin=0,restrict x to domain=0.999:5,hide obscured x ticks = false]
        \addplot[no markers,
            very thick,
            black,samples=3000,name path=A] {2*x-1+sqrt(abs(x^2-1))};
        \addplot[no markers,
            very thick,
            black,samples=3000,name path=B] {2*x-1-sqrt(abs(x^2-1))};
        \addplot[red] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip = {domain = 1:5}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Thanks!

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, ymin=0,
hide obscured x ticks=false,
]
\addplot[
name path=A,
very thick,
domain=1:5,
samples=200, smooth,
] {2*x-1+sqrt(abs(x^2-1))};
\addplot[
name path=B,
very thick,
domain=1:5,
samples=200, smooth,
] {2*x-1-sqrt(abs(x^2-1))};
\addplot[red] fill between[of=A and B];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Damn, usepgfplotslibrary, and not usetikzlibrary. That was dumb. Also, I don't know why smooth gave me weird results before, but it works fine here, so it even runs faster. Thanks a lot!
